# Get duplicate Object in array using lodash

Tags: javascript, angular

I have tried to below way to get the duplicate record, but I got the only filtered record means only an uniq record gets.

```
var filtered = _.uniqWith(form_data.itemRows, _.isEqual);
```

ArrayList:

```
 [
    {
        "PlanId": "",
        "Id": "",
        "Type": "Beverages",
        "Beverages": "2019/12/7 11:40",
        "Frequency": 1
    },
    {
        "PlanId": "",
        "Id": "",
        "Type": "Medication",
        "Beverages": "2019/12/7 11:30",
        "Frequency": 1
    },
    {
        "PlanId": "",
        "Id": "",
        "Type": "Medication",
        "Beverages": "2019/12/7 11:30",
        "Frequency": 1
    }
]
```

Type, Beverages, Frequency wise get the duplicate records.

Comment: do you want to remove the duplicate Object from the array or you only want the duplicate Object value

Comment: I want only a duplicate object value.

Comment: i have added the solution please check it @Bansi29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can do it

```js
let jsonArray = [
    {
        "PlanId": "",
        "Id": "",
        "Type": "Beverages",
        "ActivityTime": "2019/12/7 11:40",
        "Frequency": 1
    },
    {
        "PlanId": "",
        "Id": "",
        "Type": "Medication",
        "ActivityTime": "2019/12/7 11:30",
        "Frequency": 1
    },
    {
        "PlanId": "",
        "Id": "",
        "Type": "Medication",
        "ActivityTime": "2019/12/7 11:30",
        "Frequency": 1
    }
]
let Result = _.filter(
    _.uniq(
        _.map(jsonArray, function (item) {
            if (_.filter(jsonArray, {
                PlanId: item.PlanId,
                Id: item.Id,
                Type: item.Type,
                ActivityTime: item.ActivityTime,
                Frequency: item.Frequency
            }).length > 1) {
                return item
            }

            return false;
        })),
function (value) { return value; });

console.log(Result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Narendra Not only type-wise checked it check same time  & activity time and Frequency wise get the duplicate record.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this way -

```js
const arrayList =[
    {
        "PlanId": "",
        "Id": "",
        "Type": "Beverages",
        "Beverages": "2019/12/7 11:40",
        "Frequency": 1
    },
    {
        "PlanId": "",
        "Id": "",
        "Type": "Medication",
        "Beverages": "2019/12/7 11:30",
        "Frequency": 1
    },
    {
        "PlanId": "",
        "Id": "",
        "Type": "Medication",
        "Beverages": "2019/12/7 11:30",
        "Frequency": 1
    }
];
const returnObjects = _.chain(arrayList)
    .groupBy((elem) => JSON.stringify(elem))
    .reduce((nObj, obj) => {
        if (obj.length > 1) nObj.push(_.head(obj));
        return nObj
    }, [])
    .value();
console.log(returnObjects);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```